# Why don't I see the 'Winter Bash'?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

Before I went into work this morning I [downvoted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478911/pcap-create-new-file-after-each-20-mb) and got a new hat (hooray!).

However now I'm at work I do not see the hat, nor the Winter Bash icon:

[image]

I opted into Winter Bash earlier at home and also applied my shiny new hat to my profile.

I've looked around and apparently some users have been experiencing the same issue, but was caused by their timezone not being today's date yet.

However my workplace is in the same timezone, and we use GMT so it certainly is *Monday 15th*. Clearing my cache doesn't do anything.

From the [Winter Bash 2014 blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/?cb=1):

> Finally, your profile includes the number of unique <strike>snowflakes</strike> hats (You have a hat to wear!) you’ve earned all around the network.

Earlier at home I saw the snowflake icon in the section of my profile where 'profile views' is displayed, *but*...

eh, *nope*:

[image]

Can I do anything about this?

Comment: Check your dev console to see if anything is being blocked. The Winterbash uses extra JavaScript. Clear your cache if you have to.

Comment: You downvoted a question? You *monster!*

Comment: See [Where is my snowflake on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245179) as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the pointer about the developer console listing anything that is blocked- see the answer I just provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the domain hosting the extra JavaScript is being blocked by my work's network:

[image]

Going to get it unblocked.

***Edit:*** Yay (*hooray for hats!)*! :

[image]

Comment: Do you have to fill out a form with two paragraphs reasoning to get something unblocked? Or do you just casually walk up to the admins desk and tell them you want hats? :D

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I can just casually walk up to the system admins and shout 'I WANT HATS!'. As long as it's justified it can be unblocked :).

Comment: qa.sockets is the realtime updates server; AFAIK, winterbash isn't served from there. I'd worry more about the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". It looks like the domain serving winterbash is "cdn-prom.sstatic.net" - edit: balpha tells me you need "winterbash2014.stackexchange.com" too

Comment: @MarcGravell The majority of Stack Exchange used to be blocked up to the time today I had it unblocked, which is the reason why Winter Bash wasn't showing. The *only* Stack Exchange sites I could access were Stack Overflow, English Language, and Super User.

Comment: I laughed for a good 30 seconds at the image of walking up to a bunch of system admins, shouting "I WANT HATS!", and then walking away without explanation.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm assuming you actually mean `winterbash2014.stackexchange.com`, not `.se.com`, right? It doesn't appear that `se.com` is owned by Stack Exchange.

Comment: @nhinkle heh, yes - my mind automagically substitutes between those two!