# Are questions about winter bash on topic?

Tags: support, meta, winter-bash-2014

If I have a question about winter bash, can it go here on meta?  Or should it be on the global meta?

Comment: This post is so meta it hurts

Comment: and now the question is: "are questions about questions about winter bash on topic?"

Comment: How did you not explode from infinite loop on this? Did you not wonder if questions about questions about winter bash are on topic? Or questions about questions about questions about winter bash? Or..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Either one.

It will be seen by people who can answer, one way or another.

Comment: To be safe I'll just put it on global, since hats and such seem to be in scope of everything.

Comment: _@Oded_ /OT I thought hats won't be shown at meta? Is this special for mods?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ observe my edit of OP for waffles

Comment: @Compass OK, THX for clarifying. I thought, I've read so yesterday. I think I got it now: _Hats earned on SO aren't shown at MSO._ Right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's no hats or Winter Bash on child meta sites.

Comment: @cybermonkey I definitely see hats on meta.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - recent change, hats have been enabled on metas!

Comment: @cybermonkey - see above ^^^ (as of this morning)

Comment: @Oded Yeah, saw that (see my response in my answer's comment thread). Good, I was starting to miss hats on Meta :-).

Comment: @Oded Again THX for clarification. I thought the MSO hats would be given away for the MSO actions of a user solely. But anyway the policy I've seen has been changed meanwhile. That answer my /OT question.

Comment: How do I ping @πάνταῥεῖ ... owwait

Answer (score 15):

Certainly, but *only* as long as it's Stack Overflow related. The usual Meta rules apply that if a question covers all Stack Exchange sites, it should be asked on the [Stack Exchange Meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

A few questions in the [winterbash-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) tag:

- [Scroll over for winter bash not working?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280395/scroll-over-for-winter-bash-not-working)
- [Why don't I see the 'Winter Bash'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280291/why-dont-i-see-the-winter-bash)
- [Do I need to do more to earn Selfie hat?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280354/do-i-need-to-do-more-to-earn-selfie-hat)
- [St. Lucia hat awarded on the wrong date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280324/st-lucia-hat-awarded-on-the-wrong-date)

eh, *I take my [Imitation Crab](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/imitation-crab) hat off to you for this question*:

[image]

Comment: _"eh, I take my Imitation Crab hat off to you for this question:"_ What's the reason I can see it then? Did I miss something essential?